# Find a formula/function based on dataset

Tags: statistics, physics

I have an example dataset with each row having two variables.
The shown data uses Time and Distance

| Time | Distance |
| --- | --- |
| 0.2388839976 | 212.54885537138 |
| 0.3349551193 | 337.83087805091 |
| 0.3703744125 | 398.28305964308 |
| 0.4322544678 | 482.66296436682 |
| 0.5419347076 | 764.83587418504 |
| 0.612364563 | 931.07351389822 |

Given the example data in this list, how would it be possible to create a formula or function to calculate the time given a specific distance? And how would it be possible to create such a formula where you could calculate the one value given the other with an example list such as the one shown above?

Comment: It seems that, as a function of time, the distance varies as a quadratic function. Now, the problem is to find a simple formula for the reverse.

Comment: [Multiple linear regression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Simple_and_multiple_linear_regression) should do the job. Using Claude Leibovici's approach let $Y_i$ be distances $X_{1,i}$ time values and $X_{2,i}$ the squares of time values.

Comment: @ThomasPreu. I think that it is a bit more difficult since we basically need to iverse the quadratic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

As I wrote in comments, it seems that a simple quadratic regression
$$d=\alpha+\beta\,t+\gamma \,t^2$$ would be quite good.

So, solving the quadratic would give something like
$$t=\delta + \epsilon \sqrt{d+\eta}$$ would be more than decent.

This is how you need to treat the problem since you want to compute $t$.